# How do I reduce Haptic feedback intensity in CM9?

Tags: cyanogenmod, haptic-feedback

I use a CM9 rom in my Samsung Galaxy i9001. The intensity of haptic feedback is annoying, especially while unlocking the phone. I can't find an option in the settings.
Is there any related setting in Developer options / by using Terminal emulator for CyanogenMod9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CM10.1, `Settings > Advanced > Haptic`.

Comment: OK, but any idea about CM9?
The CM 10 rom is not out of the alpha stage yet for my phone.

Comment: @jadelord Have you checked if it's there? It might be the same path.

Comment: It's not. The Advanced menu opens up as Galaxy S Plus settings. The only thing that's available are Backlight settings and Horizontal calibration.

Comment: @jadelord Have you tried updating to the latest CM9 nightly? It might be there, according to this XDA post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1579919

Comment: in that case I'll just wait for the next update. I use a custom ROM - arco68's Cm9. I was looking for a hack as a solution. Thx @geffchang